# CodingBat Help. list.remove(x): x not in list error? Not understanding why this is not working

Tags: python

*"Given a non-empty string and an int n, return a new string where the char at index n has been removed. The value of n will be a valid index of a char in the original string (i.e. n will be in the range 0..len(str)-1 inclusive)*."

```
missing_char('kitten', 1) → 'ktten'
missing_char('kitten', 0) → 'itten'
missing_char('kitten', 4) → 'kittn'
```

My Solution:

```
def missing_char(str, n):
  lst = list(str)
  lst.remove([n])
  return lst
```

```
*Compile problems:
list.remove(x): x not in list*
```

Comment: you probably meant `lst.remove(n)` but that will not do what you think. [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) removes according to **element**, not **index**. What you need is `pop()`. But converting to a list is unnecessary, use slicing instead

Comment: Naming a variable `str` is a bad idea, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def missing_char(word, index):
    if len(word) > index:
        word = word[0 : index : ] + word[index + 1 : :]
        return word
    else:
        return "invalid index"

print(missing_char('kitten', 1))
# ktten
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/3d96d2cb98)